# Getting class name of a file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading a script with the function `$.getScript('myFile.js')`. I would like to find out what the class name of the file myFile.js is. How can I do this?

Content of myFile.js is:

```
class myFile {
    static Do_something() {
        console.log('Hello');
    }
}
```

Comment: @Teemu OP is asking to get the class that is defined in the file. AKA https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: @rmlan hey look at that edit.... I must be a mind reader.

Comment: Only way really would be to parse it as a text file and read it.

Comment: @Teemu my file has a class. I have edited my question.

Comment: you have to parse it as a text file and look for the pattern/value you're interested in. Maybe a regular expression would help. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ajax and some regex...

```
function getClassNamesInFile(file){
  return new Promise(done=>{
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'text',
      url: file
    }).done(txt=>{
      var classes = (txt.match(/class ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g) || {})
        .map(itm=>itm.split(" ").pop());
      done(classes);
    });
  });
}
```

Use it like this...

```
getClassNamesInFile('myFile.js').then(function(classNames){
  console.log(classNames);
});
```

[Here's a demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/qyZURlHuUAHU0Qq5Goae?p=preview).

---

If you also need to add the file (like `$.getScript` does), you can do this...

```
function getClassNamesInFile(file, runFile=false){
  return new Promise(done=>{
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'text',
      url: file
    }).done(txt=>{
      var classes = txt.match(/class ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g)
        .map(itm=>itm.split(" ").pop());
      if(!runFile) return done(classes);
      let scr = document.createElement("script");
      scr.onload = ()=>done(classes);
      scr.setAttribute('src', file);
      document.body.appendChild(scr);
    });
  });
}

getClassNamesInFile('myFile.js', true).then(function(classNames){
  console.log(classNames);
  if(~classNames.indexOf('myFile')) myFile.Do_something();
});
```

[Here's a demo for that](https://plnkr.co/edit/D1dcr4K9i552PsGmQRXG?p=preview)..

Comment: Great answer! Thank you!!